# ILNumerics ILPanel Draw to Bitmap?

Tags: ilnumerics

I would like to create a picture of the ILPanel and copy it to the clipboard or save to disk.
Unfortunately, I always get a white image.

Code:

```
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(ilpnlChart.Bounds.Width, ilpnlChart.Bounds.Height);
ilpnlChart.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, ilpnlChart.Bounds);

Clipboard.SetImage(bitmap);

// TEST
bitmap.Save(@"C:\Temp\chart.jpg");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an GDI or SVG renderer in order to export your scene to a static image.

Take a look at http://ilnumerics.net/offscreen-rendering.html

Comment: Thank you. Somehow I find myself not cope on your website. I've already searched there, but have not found the answer. :-)